# How to partially differentiate tu[t]u'[t] with respect to t

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

How can I partially differentiate `tu[t]u'[t]` with respect to `t` in *Mathematica*?

Comment: Why would that be partial? D[func[t],t]

Comment: Oh, just in case: `tu[t]` and `t u[t]` are two different things in *Mathematica*.

Comment: @m_goldberg, I don't believe we're sure if the OP intended the omitted space, or not…

Comment: @J.M. OK, I rolled it back and re-edited.

Comment: @Sinu Vasan you are making unnecessarily difficult for people to help you. Why would you only offer the information that the expected result should be  
it should be $u(t)u'(t)$ and that the problem is related to *Noether's Theorem* after you received answers? Why haven't you show your due diligence, your code attempts? Only [good questions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) deserve to get great answers.

Comment: I'm reluctant to vote to close, as this is apparently a real application in Lagrangian mechanics, as noted by @march, but the quality of the question certainly earns a downvote.

Answer (score 7):

I believe this is what the OP means:

```
Dt[t u[t] u'[t], t, Constants -> {u[t], u'[t]}]
(* u[t] Derivative[1][u][t] *)
```

In Lagrangian mechanics, *functional* derivatives are taken all over the place, and so a partial derivative with respect to $t$ means assume coordinates (`u[t]`) and velocities (`u'[t]`) are *constant* and only differentiate parts that are *explicitly* functions of `t`.