# How to define a formula-less function?

Tags: functions, parametric-functions

How can I tell Mathematica that $f(t)$ is a function of time without providing it with a formula?

I want to write an auto Lagrangian calculator.
And a derivative taker is needed which writes the derivative of those un-formulated functions like this: $\dot f(t)$ or $\ddot f(t)$

How is it possible to have a function without formula and wherever a calculation was needed to be done to the function, be parametric?

An example with formula:
[image: formula]

What to do, in my case, that the derivative gets output like `f'[t]`? (actually it can't be other than that because there is no formula to take the derivative of!)

Comment: You can use `f'[t]` to represent the derivative of `f[t]` and you can use it like this: `D[(f'[t])^2, t]`. Can you give an example to better illustrate what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Szabolcs I clarified the case.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: See http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/4656/

Comment: You can just do as I suggested in the comment.  Use `phi[t]` to represent a function, `phi'[t]` for its derivative, etc.  No definitions needed.  This is valid: `a = D[(phi'[t])^2, t]`.  And so is this:  `D[a, phi'[t]]`.

Comment: Without a specific example (written in properly formatted *Mathematica* code), it's hard to help you with your problem. However, perhaps [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/107751/29734) will be of use to you.

Comment: You quite explicitly already told MMA, that `f[t]` is a function of time. Is your question about getting it to display the result  in a specific way (i.e. the dots above f)?

Comment: @LLlAMnYP. I want NO numbers and known terms in my calculations. pure parametric is what I want.

Comment: Well, there are no numbers or known terms in a generic `f[t]` so I'm struggling to see, what the problem is. Just don't give `f[t]` any definitions.

Comment: I still don't understand your question.  You did not address my two previous comments, and you did not give an example of what you tried so far.  You have a screenshot where you defined `f`.  As I said, that is not necessary. Use `f[t]` to represent the function and give no definition to `f`.  Voting to close until the question is made clear, with specific examples of what you want to do.

Comment: Perhaps, post factum, I'm bettering understanding your confusion. The point is, that you don't need to declare functions and variables in Mathematica. Just as you would abstractly write down `f(t)` in a notebook (with pen and paper), so you can, type, use and manipulate an abstract `f[t]` in Mathematica. You get a formula-less function simply by not defining it with a formula.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that @LLIAMnYP has already answered your question but perhaps an example will help. Building off your suggestion from classical mechanics:

```
lag=1/2 m x1'[t]^2-m g x1[t]
el[q_] := D[lag, q] - Dt[ D[lag, D[q, t]] , t] == 0;
el[x1[t]]
(* x1''[t]= g *)
```

The first term on the lhs would take the derivative of `lag` with respect to `x1[t]` which is just `-m g`

Notice that the `D` function takes derivatives in terms of whatever you specify. In the second term of the lhs since `x1[t]` is a function of time (since I put time as an argument) the `D[q,t]` will give me `x1'[t]` and the derivative of `lag` in terms of `x'[t]` is `m x1'[t]`. Then the total derivative `Dt` with respect to time of this expression is `m x1''[t]`.

Nowhere have I provided a formula for `x1[t]`.

Comment: yup. It worked. look guys . this was what I needed: the output is parametric. http://www.uplooder.net/img/image/76/bbef69eb6484cb96c0029bd4f11df3ac/2016-03-13-07-51-53-abctest.nb.png

Comment: Make sure you declare that `m` is a constant!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you're overcomplicating things. I'm guessing your goal can be achieved with a standard package:

```
Needs["VariationalMethods`"]
Clear[f,t,U]
lagrangian = f'[t]^2 - U[f[t]]

EulerEquations[lagrangian, f[t], t]
(* ==> -Derivative[1][U][f[t]] - 2 (f^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t] == 0 *)
```

See the tutorial for the [VariationalMethods](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/VariationalMethods/tutorial/VariationalMethods.html) package.